# php - How to use laravel explode from the slash (/) and get the last word

Tags: php, laravel, explode

Hi im really newbie in Laravel. So i really need some help, i need to get the last word from $report->reportable_type and from the reportable_type it contains App/Models/Store and App/Models/Product. So i want to explode the slash (/) and get the last word it means store or product.

The code in my controller its worked but it using print_r and i didnt want to use the print_r.

This is my Controller

```
public function toLink($id)
{
    $report = $this->reportRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    //get Store Name
    $name = Store::where('id','=',$report->reportable_id)->pluck('name')->all();
    $storename = $name[0];

    //get Store ID
    $idstore = Store::where('id','=',$report->reportable_id)->pluck('id')->all();
    $storeid = $idstore[0];

    if(empty($report))
    {
        Flash::error('Report not found');
        return redirect(route('reports.index'));
    }

    $report_type = $report->reportable_type;
    print_r (explode("/",strrpos($report_type, '/') + 1),$report_type);
    return redirect(env('FRONTEND_URL') ."/".str_slug($reportable_type)."/$storeid/".str_slug($storename));


}
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Friendly reminder: [Avoid posting code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285554#285554). Instead, copy & paste the code text into question body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Laravel helper function [`class_basename`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-class-basename) does just that.

```
$type = class_basename($report->reportable_type);
```

**Update:**
If you really want to use the explode function, you can use the Laravel [`last`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-last) helper to get the last element of an array.

```
$type = last(explode('/', $report->reportable_type));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me whether the class_basename is explode from each slash and take the last word ? App/Models/Store and App/Models/Product and i want to get the last word it means store and product, but thanks for the help

Comment: @SahatRiyanto click the link and you'll see the description of the helper: The `class_basename` returns the class name of the given class with the class' namespace removed. Also, there is an example in docs.

Comment: @Jerodev ya thats worked :DDDD but can u give me another answer with using laravel explode function? really thanks for ur help :D

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin ya thanks for the answer and its worked but can you give me another answer with using laravel explode function? :DDD

Comment: Why would you want to use the explode function when you have this helper?

Comment: @Jerodev My teacher told me to try to use the laravel explode function :D but really thanks for the help

Comment: @Jerodev WOH both of the answers its worked really thanks for your help :D god bless you